# How to post-process <jdoc:include type="head" /> in PHP

Tags: php, joomla, joomla3.0, joomla-extensions

*Initial problem:*

I am using a particular Joomla plugin which is very good in many ways. However, it adds a bunch of Javascript to my `<head>` element which I do not desire. (I am by no means philosophically against the plugin using Javascript. It's just that the Javascript output by the plugin is bad. Perhaps not bad in the general case, but it breaks what I'm trying to do with my site. Anyway, I'm going off on a tangent. I'll rein it in...)

So my solution is that I want to control what `<jdoc:include type="head" />` includes in my page. I want to strip out that bad piece of Javascript. But how?

*My first attempt:*

Being fairly knowledgeable about PHP if not about Joomla, my initial thought was... "aha! output buffering!"

I added `<?php ob_start(); ?>` to my template before `<jdoc:include type="head" />` and did a little `ob_get_contents()` stuff afterwards. But of course, this just literally captures the string `'<jdoc:include type="head" />'`. It is only later; after the template has finished running that the jdoc includes are processed. Silly me.

So how do I cut this crud out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given you're "knowledgeable about PHP" I would suggest not using a hack like this as it's likely to break in a future update of Joomla.

All plugins are `php`, you could edit that rather than  creating an override that replaces a fairly core file.

It's also pretty easy to create a [plugin](http://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_Plugin_for_Joomla) that traps various system [triggers/events](http://docs.joomla.org/Plugin/Events), if you didn't want to edit the original plugin. [Joomla Doc's](http://docs.joomla.org/) has a whole category on [Plugin Development](http://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_Plugin_for_Joomla).

I would imagine a `System` plugin that handles on the render or head events would be the place to trap it at, i.e. `onAfterRender`, `onBeforeRender` or `onBeforeCompileHead`

Alternatively you could try a plugin like this one "[Skyline Script Remover](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/core-enhancements/performance/scripts/21982)" from the [Joomla Extension directory](http://extensions.joomla.org/), found in [this search](http://extensions.joomla.org/search?q=remove%20script).

Answer (score 3):

To prevent the output of javascript-Tags you have to unset the correct member of `$this->_scripts` in your template before the `<jdoc:incldue type="head" />`.
For example, if the Joomla head adds `<script type="text/javascript" src="/media/jui/js/jquery.min.js"></script>` then add the following php code before it:

```
unset($this->_scripts['/media/jui/js/jquery.min.js']);
```

Try `var_dump($this->_scripts`); to see all members in it.

Comment: Unfortunately it's *not* a `<script src=...>` element, but a `<script>...</script>` one. It does not appear in `$this->_scripts`, or at least doesn't at the time the template `index.php` is being executed.

Comment: Then check `$this->_script` instead of `$this->_scripts` (trailing s removed)

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that I did a full `print_r($this)` and the script does not appear *anywhere* at the time the template's `index.php` is being executed. It is presumably added to `$this` later on, but I have no idea how to manipulate `$this` after the template has been run.

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question; I'm using something along [these lines](http://www.admin-enclave.com/en/tutorials/joomla/36-customize-the-jdoc-include-type-head-part.html).

First, copy `/libraries/joomla/document/html/renderer/head.php` to `/templates/MYTEMPLATE/renderer_head.php`.

Then alter the `fetchHead` method in `/templates/MYTEMPLATE/renderer_head.php` to suppress the parts that I don't want.

Lastly, in `/templates/MYTEMPLATE/index.php`, add the following line near the top:

```
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'renderer_head.php';
```